# Unable to rename and delete my pdf file in my Android App

Tags: java, android-studio, delete-file, file-rename, android-storage

I am unable to rename and delete  the pdf file in my pdf reader app using renameTo() method to rename the file and file.delete() method is also not working to delete the pdf file from the internal storage.
I am attaching all related code from my Android studio that might help to find the poblem:

My RecyclerAdapter code where i am trying to rename and delete the file based on MenuItem Selection:

```
   @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_delete:
                int position = getBindingAdapterPosition();

                File file=pdf.get(position);
                file.delete();
                pdf.remove(position);
                notifyItemChanged(position);
                notifyItemRangeChanged(position,pdf.size());
                return true;
            case R.id.menu_rename:
                AlertDialog.Builder jumpto = new AlertDialog.Builder(mcontext);
                jumpto.setTitle("Rename");
                EditText page = new EditText(mcontext);
                page.setText(pdfname.getText());
                jumpto.setView(page);
                jumpto.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        File old = new File(pdf.get(getBindingAdapterPosition()).getAbsolutePath());
                        String name = old.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath();
                        String newpath = name + page.getText().toString();
                        File newfile = new File(newpath);

                        Boolean rename = old.renameTo(newfile);
                        if (rename) {
                            ContentResolver resolver = mcontext.getContentResolver();
                            resolver.delete(MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"), MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=?", new
                                    String[]{
                                    old.getAbsolutePath()});
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
                            intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(newfile));
                            mcontext.getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
                        }
                       
                    }

                });
```

Here is the code of how i am fetching pdf file from storage in my Documents Fragment:

```
 protected List<File> getPdfList() {
    Uri collection;

    final String[] projection = new String[]{
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_ADDED,
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA,
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE,
    };

    final String sortOrder = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_ADDED + " DESC";

    final String selection = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + " = ?";

    final String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("pdf");
    final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{mimeType};

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        collection = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL);
    }else{
        collection = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");
    }


    try (Cursor cursor =getContext().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(collection, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder)) {
        assert cursor != null;

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int columnData = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA);
            int columnName = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
            String path=cursor.getString(columnData);
            if(new File(path).exists()){
            do {
                pdf.add(new File((cursor.getString(columnData))));
               // Log.d(TAG, "getPdf: " + cursor.getString(columnData));
                //you can get your pdf files
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    }
    return pdf;
}
```

Here is my MainActivity.java code where i am asking for Runtime permission:

```
 if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED&&ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
           
        } else {
            requestStoragePermission();

        }

    }

    int Request_Code = 12;
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private void requestStoragePermission() {

        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, Request_Code);

    }



    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (requestCode == Request_Code) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
               
            }
        } else {

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check that your file is deleted or not for this you can check this may help you here is the code for delete

```
boolean b = documentList.get(position).getFile().delete();
if (b) {
   documentList.remove(position);
   notifyItemRemoved(position);
   notifyDataSetChanged();
   Toast.makeText(context, "File Deleted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else {
   Toast.makeText(context, "File Deletion Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: what issue you are facing?

Comment: The file is getting deleted from recycler view but not from storage.When i close my app and restart it then the deleted file reappear.

Comment: if the file is deleted then b returns the true if it is true then the file is removed from the list. there is something else issue you are facing.

Comment: one thing more you are getting the absolute path for deleting the file.

Comment: Thankew Rafaqat for your time.I added content resolver to delete my file and now its working fine.